# How to change a code for an I2C 16x2 to a 20x4?

Tags: arduino-mega, i2c, rotary-encoder

I have found a sketch that someone wrote for a rotary encoder controlled LCD menu.

The code is for an I<sup>2</sup>C that is 16x2 and I have an I<sup>2</sup>C that is 20x4. With the code that I found, the layers are all 3 lines, so when they appear on the LCD, it is on 2 "pages".  Since my LCD is 20x4, I don't need to scroll to a second page.

How do I get that third line on the same page as the first two?  I am also still looking at other sketches people have posted for LCD menus, but most of them seem to have outdated libraries or are for 16x2 screens.

```
#include <OneButton.h>
#include <Encoder.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LCD.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C  lcd(0x27, 2,1,0,4,5,6,7);

// ROTARY ENCODER
long oldPosition  = 0;
int encoderDTpin = 34;
int encoderCLKpin = 30;
Encoder myEnc(encoderDTpin, encoderCLKpin);

int buttonPin = 26;
OneButton button0(buttonPin, true);


// MENU ARRAY 
// First number in array = amount of menu items in root layer. Same goes for next layer. 
//(Example: first value in array is 4. This means Layer 0 has 4 menu items. Layer 1 has only 2 menu items.)
// First number infront of menu text is the layer number that item points to. (Example: 1_Rotation points to Layer 1)
// Second number infront of menu text is the number of the value connected to that menu item in the values array. 
//(Example: 15Direction points to position 5 in the values array)

String menu[] = {"4","1__Rotation","056Active","3__Watches","4__Item4",       // Layer 0
                 "3","100Rotations","105Direction","109Speed",                // Layer 1
                 "3","256Active","2__Item2.2","2__Item2.3",                    // Layer 2
                 "4","4__Watch 1","3__Watch 2","3__Watch 3","3__Watch 4",     // Layer 3
                 "2","4__Item3.1.1","4__Item3.1.2"};                          // Layer 4

// VALUES ARRAY
// TYPES, 1 numeric / 2 character value range
// 1 - type,value,increments,min,max
// 2 - type,starting value in options array,lowest value options array,max value options array
int values[] = {1,11,25,50,1450, //0-4 WATCH1
                2,2,0,2,         //5-8
                1,600,25,75,600, //9-13

                1,11,25,50,1450, //14-18 WATCH2
                2,2,0,2,         //19-22
                1,600,25,75,600, //23-27

                1,11,25,50,1450, //28-32 WATCH3
                2,2,0,2,         //33-36
                1,600,25,75,600, //37-41

                1,11,25,50,1450, //42-46 WATCH4
                2,2,0,2,         //47-50
                1,600,25,75,600, //51-55

                2,4,3,4,         //56-59 WATCH1 ACTIVE
                2,4,3,4,         //60-63 WATCH2 ACTIVE
                2,4,3,4,         //64-67 WATCH3 ACTIVE
                2,4,3,4};        //68-71 WATCH4 ACTIVE


String options[] = {"CW","CCW","MIX",
                    "No","Yes"};                 

// Custom character for LCD.
byte cursor[8] = {
  0b10000,
  0b10000,
  0b01000,
  0b00110,
  0b01000,
  0b10000,
  0b10000,
  0b00000
};

byte watch[8] = {
  0b01110,
  0b01110,
  0b11011,
  0b10001,
  0b10001,
  0b11011,
  0b01110,
  0b01110
};


int currentType = 0;
int value = 0;
int numIncr = 0;
int Min = 0;
int Max = 0;

int currentLayer = 0;
int lastLayer = 99;
int currentLength = menu[0].toInt();
int currentPosition = 0;
int currentSelect = 1;
int currentChange = 0;
String currentPress = "";
float currentlcdLayerFloat = 0;
int currentlcdLayer = 0;
int lastlcdLayer = 0;
int lcdUpdated = 0;
int currentLine = 0;
int cursorLayer = 0;
int cursorPosition = 0;
int valueLength = 0;

/*
int homeScreen = 1;

String currentTime = "00:00:00";
String lastTime = "00:00:00";
String temptime = "00";
String currentDate = "";

int watch1active = values[56] - 3;
int watch2active = values[60] - 3;
int watch3active = values[64] - 3;
int watch4active = values[68] - 3;
int watch1rotations = 0;
int watch2rotations = 0;
int watch3rotations = 0;
int watch4rotations = 0;
int watch1left = values[1];
int watch2left = values[15];
int watch3left = values[29];
int watch4left = values[43];
String temprotationsleft = "";
*/


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Map rotary button to actions single and doubleclick.
  button0.attachClick(singleClick);
  button0.attachDoubleClick(doubleClick);

  lcd.begin (16,2);
  lcd.setBacklightPin(3,POSITIVE);
  lcd.setBacklight(HIGH);
  lcd.home();

  // Create the custom character.
  lcd.createChar(0, cursor);
  lcd.createChar(1, watch);

  lcd.setCursor (2,0);  
  lcd.print("Watch Winder");
  delay(1000);
  clearLine(0);

  // Set the select cursor on the first line.
  cursorLayer = 0;
  lcd.setCursor (0,cursorLayer);  
  writeCursor();

}

void loop() {

    // Listen to button presses.
    button0.tick();

    // Listen if the rotary encoder moves.
    rotary_check();

    // Print the LCD menu.
    lcdMenu();

}

void singleClick() {

  // IF current layer number is the same as redirect layer number, we stay on the same layer
  // AND no item is selected in the menu
  // AND the selected item has a redirect to another layer
  if(currentLayer == menu[currentPosition + currentSelect].substring(0,1).toInt() 
      && menu[currentPosition + currentSelect].substring(1,3) != "__" && currentPress == ""){

    currentPress = menu[currentPosition + currentSelect].substring(3);
    currentChange = menu[currentPosition + currentSelect].substring(1,3).toInt();

    Serial.println("Currentpress: " + currentPress);

    currentType = values[currentChange];
    value = values[currentChange + 1];

    // Type select change is numeric
    if(currentType == 1){
      Min = values[currentChange + 3];
      Max = values[currentChange + 4];
      numIncr = values[currentChange + 2];

      Serial.println("Currentvalue: " + String(value));
      Serial.println("Increments: " + String(numIncr));
      Serial.println("Min: " + String(Min));
      Serial.println("Max: " + String(Max));


      valueLength = String(value).length();

    // Type select change is character range
    } else if(currentType == 2){
      Min = values[currentChange + 2];
      Max = values[currentChange + 3];

      Serial.println("Currentvalue: " + options[value]);
      Serial.println("Options: ");

      for (int i=Min; i <= Max; i++){
        Serial.println(options[i]);
      }

      valueLength = options[value].length();

    }

    clearSelect();
    cursorPosition = 15 - valueLength;
    lcd.setCursor(cursorPosition,cursorLayer);
    writeCursor();

  // ELSE IF something is selected in the menu, and the button is pressed again. We deselect the item.  
  } else if(currentPress != ""){

    currentValues();
    currentPress = "";
    currentChange = 0;

    clearChar(cursorPosition,cursorLayer);
    lcd.setCursor(0,cursorLayer);
    writeCursor();

  // IF nothing is selected and nothing will be deselected, move to the redirect layer listed in the first position of the array.  
  } else {

    currentLayer = menu[currentPosition + currentSelect].substring(0,1).toInt();
    currentSelect = 1;
    currentlcdLayerFloat = 0;
    currentlcdLayer = 0;
    lastlcdLayer = 0;

    clearSelect();
    cursorLayer = 0;
    lcd.setCursor (0,cursorLayer);  
    writeCursor();

  }

}

// Reset to layer 0.
void doubleClick() {
  if(currentLayer == 0){
    currentLayer = 0;
    currentSelect = 1;
    currentlcdLayerFloat = 0;
    currentlcdLayer = 0;
    lastlcdLayer = 0;

    clearSelect();
    cursorLayer = 0;

    lcd.clear();
    lcdUpdated = 0;
  }
  if(currentLayer != 0){
    currentLayer = 0;
    currentSelect = 1;
    currentlcdLayerFloat = 0;
    currentlcdLayer = 0;
    lastlcdLayer = 0;

    clearSelect();
    cursorLayer = 0;
    lcd.setCursor (0,cursorLayer);  
    writeCursor();
  }
}

void rotary_check(){

  // Constantly read the position of the rotary encoder
  long newPosition = myEnc.read() / 4;

  // IF the new position of the encoder is different then the old position
  if (newPosition != oldPosition) {

    // IF nothing has been selected in the menu
    if(currentPress == ""){

      if(newPosition > oldPosition && currentSelect < currentLength){
        clearSelect();
        currentSelect++;
        currentlcdLayerFloat = currentlcdLayerFloat + 0.5;
        currentlcdLayer = currentlcdLayerFloat;

        cursorSelect();

        lcd.setCursor (0,cursorLayer);  
        writeCursor();
        Serial.println("> " + menu[currentPosition + currentSelect].substring(3));

      } else if (newPosition < oldPosition && currentSelect != 1){
        clearSelect();
        currentSelect--;
        currentlcdLayerFloat = currentlcdLayerFloat - 0.5;
        currentlcdLayer = currentlcdLayerFloat;

        cursorSelect();

        lcd.setCursor (0,cursorLayer);  
        writeCursor();
        Serial.println("> " + menu[currentPosition + currentSelect].substring(3));

      }

      if(lastlcdLayer != currentlcdLayer){
        lcdUpdated = 0;
      }

      lastlcdLayer = currentlcdLayer;      
      oldPosition = newPosition;



    // IF something has been selected in the menu, we are going to change the value of a menu item.
    } else if(currentPress != ""){


      lcd.setCursor(cursorPosition + 1,cursorLayer);
      // IF the new position is HIGHER then the old position
      if(newPosition > oldPosition){
        clearChar(cursorPosition,cursorLayer);

        // IF the selected item has a change type that is NUMERIC.
        // AND the MAXIMUM of the selected item has not been reached. 
        // We change the value UPWARDS with the icrements listed in the array.
        // SAME applies for next ELSE IF, just for the change type character. And the next ELSE IF we just go down.
        if(currentType == 1 && value < Max){
            value = value + numIncr;
            values[currentChange + 1] = value;
            Serial.println(value);

            clearValue();
            valueLength = String(value).length();
            cursorPosition = 15 - valueLength;
            lcd.setCursor(cursorPosition + 1,cursorLayer);
            lcd.print(value);
          }

        if(currentType == 2 && value < Max){
            value++;
            values[currentChange + 1] = value;
            Serial.println(options[value]);

            clearValue();
            valueLength = options[value].length();
            cursorPosition = 15 - valueLength;
            lcd.setCursor(cursorPosition + 1,cursorLayer);
            lcd.print(options[value]);
          }
          lcd.setCursor(cursorPosition,cursorLayer);
          writeCursor();

      } else {
        clearChar(cursorPosition,cursorLayer);

        if(currentType == 1 && value > Min){
          value = value - numIncr;
          values[currentChange + 1] = value;
          Serial.println(value);

          clearValue();
          valueLength = String(value).length();
          cursorPosition = 15 - valueLength;
          lcd.setCursor(cursorPosition + 1,cursorLayer);
          lcd.print(value);
        }

        if(currentType == 2 && value > Min){
            value--;
            values[currentChange + 1] = value;
            Serial.println(options[value]);

            clearValue();
            valueLength = options[value].length();
            cursorPosition = 15 - valueLength;
            lcd.setCursor(cursorPosition + 1,cursorLayer);
            lcd.print(options[value]);
          }
          lcd.setCursor(cursorPosition,cursorLayer);
          writeCursor();

      }



      oldPosition = newPosition;
    } else {
      oldPosition = newPosition;
    }



  }
}

void lcdMenu(){
  if (lastLayer != currentLayer || lcdUpdated == 0){

    currentLength = menu[0].toInt();
    currentPosition = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < currentLayer; i++){
      currentPosition = (menu[currentPosition].toInt() + 1) + currentPosition;
      currentLength = menu[currentPosition].toInt();
    }

    clearMenu();
    int tempPosition = currentPosition;

    if(currentlcdLayer != 0){

      currentPosition = currentPosition + (currentlcdLayer * 2);
    }

    Serial.println("LCD-------------");

    for (int i=1; i <= 2; i++){
      lcd.setCursor (1,i - 1);  
      lcd.print(menu[currentPosition + i].substring(3));

      currentType = 0;
      value = values[menu[currentPosition + i].substring(1,3).toInt() + 1];
      String tempvalue = "";

      if(menu[currentPosition + i].substring(1,3) != "__" && menu[currentPosition + i].substring(1,3) != ""){
        currentType = values[menu[currentPosition + i].substring(1,3).toInt()];
        if(currentType == 1){
          lcd.setCursor (16 - String(value).length(),i - 1);
          lcd.print(value);
          tempvalue = " "+ String(value);
        }else if(currentType == 2){
          lcd.setCursor (16 - options[value].length(),i - 1);
          lcd.print(options[value]);
          tempvalue = " "+ options[value];
        } 

      }

      Serial.println(menu[currentPosition + i].substring(3) + tempvalue);
    }
    Serial.println("----------------");

    currentPosition = tempPosition;
    lastLayer = currentLayer;
    lcdUpdated = 1;

    /**
    Serial.println("Layer " + String(currentLayer + 1));
    Serial.println("Layer length " + String(currentLength));
    Serial.println("Layer position " + String(currentPosition));
    **/

  }
}


void currentValues(){

  Serial.println("Currentpress: " + currentPress);

  if(currentType == 1){
      Serial.println("Currentvalue: " + String(value));
      Serial.println("Increments: " + String(numIncr));
      Serial.println("Min: " + String(Min));
      Serial.println("Max: " + String(Max));

    } else if(currentType == 2){
      Serial.println("Currentvalue: " + options[value]);
      Serial.println("Options: ");

      for (int i=Min; i <= Max; i++){
        Serial.println(options[i]);
      }
    }
}

void clearChar(int charPosition, int line){
  lcd.setCursor (charPosition,line);
  lcd.print(" ");
}

void clearLine(int line){
  lcd.setCursor (0,line);
  lcd.print("                ");
}

void clearMenu(){
  lcd.setCursor (1,0);
  lcd.print("               ");
  lcd.setCursor (1,1);
  lcd.print("               ");
}

void clearSelect(){
  lcd.setCursor (0,0);
  lcd.print(" ");
  lcd.setCursor (0,1);
  lcd.print(" ");
}

void cursorSelect(){
  switch (currentSelect){
          case 1:
            cursorLayer = 0;
            break;
          case 2:
            cursorLayer = 1;
            break;
          case 3:
            cursorLayer = 0;
            break;
          case 4:
            cursorLayer = 1;
            break;
          case 5:
            cursorLayer = 0;
            break;
          case 6:
            cursorLayer = 1;
            break;
        }
}

void writeCursor(){
  lcd.write(byte(0));
}

void clearValue(){
  for (int i = 16 - valueLength; i <= 16; i++){
        lcd.setCursor (i,cursorLayer);
        lcd.print(" ");
      }


}
```

Comment: or use and existing menu library https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=arduino+menu&type=

Answer (score 1):

Change line

```
lcd.begin (16,2);
```

to

```
lcd.begin (20,4);
```

then position cursor as you did for lines 0 & 1.